# Can I use X3D with Google's Dart programming language for the web?

Tags: dart, x3d

Can I use X3D with Google's Dart programming language for the web?

Currently HTML5 allows a person to integrate X3DOM with the WebGL JavaScript API.

Is there an analogous way of integrating X3D with Google Dart?

Answer (score 1):

If you can do something in Js you can do it in Dart (either with Dart natively or with `dart:js` - See [Using JavaScript from Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/)).